# how to send 32bits frame at once from efm32 controller

Tags: embedded

I am trying to send 32bits at once from my USART in my efm32 controller.
I improvised the following way where i define usart frame register first 4 bitfield as 13(to have 16 bit frame as shown in manual bellow)using

```
USART0->FRAME=USART0->FRAME&(0xFFFFFFF<<4) //leaving all bits except the first 4
USART0->FRAME=USART0->FRAME|(0b1010)
```

Using the TXDOUBLE register i put the first 16 variable in 0-15 place and  second 16bit variable  at 16-31 places using(as shown in the manual bellow)

```
USART0->TXDOUBLE=(USART0->TXDOUBLE)&(0xFFFF<<16)//zeros at b15-b0
USART0->TXDOUBLE=USART0->TXDOUBLE|TxBuffer[0]; //setting b15-b0  
USART0->TXDOUBLE=(USART0->TXDOUBLE)&(0xFFFF)//zeros at b31-b16
USART0->TXDOUBLE=USART0->TXDOUBLE|(TxBuffer[1]<<16); //setting b31-b16
```

Is this a valid method?
Did i implemented correctly the bitfield value setting?
The full code is shown bellow.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

```
#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE   2
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE   TX_BUFFER_SIZE

//W/R=0 write and update channeL0  all1 data    dont cate
uint16_t TxBuffer[TX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0b0000001100001111,0b1111111111110000};


uint32_t TxBufferIndex = 0;

uint8_t RxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint32_t RxBufferIndex = 0;

volatile uint32_t msTicks; /* counts 1ms timeTicks */

void Delay(uint32_t dlyTicks);

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  msTicks++;       /* increment counter necessary in Delay()*/
}

void Delay(uint32_t dlyTicks)
{
  uint32_t curTicks;

  curTicks = msTicks;
  while ((msTicks - curTicks) < dlyTicks) ;
}

int main(void)
{
  // Initialize chip
  CHIP_Init();
  if (SysTick_Config(CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE) / 1000)) {
        while (1) ;
  }

  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 12, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_CLK is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 2, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_CS is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 10, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_TX (MOSI) is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 11, gpioModeInput, 1);    // US1_RX (MISO) is input
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 3, gpioModePushPull, 0);    // LDAC
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 1, gpioModePushPull, 1);    // CLR
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Start with default config, then modify as necessary
   USART_InitSync_TypeDef config = USART_INITSYNC_DEFAULT;
   config.master       = true;            // master mode
   config.baudrate     = 1000000;         // CLK freq is 1 MHz
   config.autoCsEnable = false;            // CS pin controlled by hardware, not firmware
   config.clockMode    = usartClockMode0; // clock idle low, sample on rising/first edge
   config.msbf         = true;            // send MSB first

   USART_InitSync(USART0, &config);
   USART0->ROUTE = USART_ROUTE_CLKPEN | USART_ROUTE_TXPEN | USART_ROUTE_RXPEN | USART_ROUTE_LOCATION_LOC0;
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   USART_Enable(USART0, usartEnable);
    TxBufferIndex = 0;
    USART0->IEN = USART_IEN_TXC; //enable TXC interrupt flag
    USART0->FRAME=USART0->FRAME&(0xFFFFFFF<<4) //leaving all bits except the first 4
    USART0->FRAME=USART0->FRAME|(0b1010)


  while(1)
  {
      Delay(1);
        GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,2);
        USART0->TXDOUBLE=(USART0->TXDOUBLE)&(0xFFFF<<16)//zeros at b15-b0
        USART0->TXDOUBLE=USART0->TXDOUBLE|TxBuffer[0]; //setting b15-b0  
        USART0->TXDOUBLE=(USART0->TXDOUBLE)&(0xFFFF)//zeros at b31-b16
        USART0->TXDOUBLE=USART0->TXDOUBLE|(TxBuffer[1]<<16); //setting b31-b16
          while( !(USART0->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );  //wait TILL TXC goes high
          GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,2);
      Delay(2000);


  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What data format does the slave expect? If the slave works in the regular 8bit mode, then use 8bit mode and send four single bytes.

Comment: Hello,Slave expects to recieves conitues 32bit cammand(clock doesn stop)
if is send four times 8bits then clk stops in between i get clock gaps.
it sends 8 bits clock pause ,sends 8 bits clock pause, sends 8 bits clock pause ,sends 8 bits clock pause .

Comment: Is this SPI? Or what is the protocol? In SPI, gaps are no problem at all as long as the chip select stays asserted. The slave will look at the clock signal to determine when the next bit is ready.

Comment: YES it is SPI for DAC80004 and xr25 flash.
for general knowledge is my method correct?

Comment: For general knowledge: No, there are several problems. The upper 16 bits of TXDOUBLE are always ignored. Even if your UART was configured to work in 16bit mode, you make 4 writes resulting in 64 bits being transmitted. You don't initialize `config.databits` possibly resulting in undefined behavior. The FRAME register has only 8 relevant bits; you configure strange stopbits and 13 databits. You enable interrupts but use the TXC status bit to wait for completion. I'm afraid you have misunderstood several parts.

Comment: Hello ,instaed of config.databits i write the value 13 to the fram register the the databits bitframe by the manual 13 with devine 16 bits per frame.
I thought i should enable TXC interupt  in order to use TXC status bits.
So in the TXDOUBLE register i can write only 16 bits at most.
So 16 bits is the maximum i can send per frame?
There is not some other option?
I realy want to have 32 bit frame with no CLK shutting down in between,

Comment: I had a look at the DAC80004 data sheet. It will nicely work if you pull SYNC low, send 4 bytes and then pull SYNC high again. At the most, the CLK will be slightly stretched between bytes. It will not be *shut down* (whatever that is supposed to mean). You are making your life unnecessarily hard. And `0b1010` is not 13. It's 10 and therefore configures 13 bits.

Comment: And you should stop writing code like `USART0->TXDOUBLE=(USART0->TXDOUBLE)&(0xFFFF<<16); USART0->TXDOUBLE=USART0->TXDOUBLE|TxBuffer[0];` because `USART0->TXDOUBLE` is not a variable but a peripheral register. So reads and writes have side effect. Each assignment transmits data. Each read takes data from the FIFO. And they both change status bits. I don't think you wanted to transmit two frames and read one frame with these two statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code how it could work. It's a shot into the dark as I've never used an EFM32 and had no way of compiling or otherwise verifying the code. (I don't understand the purpose of `USART0->ROUTE` so I just copied it over.)

```
uint8_t TxBuffer[] = { 0b00000011, 0b00001111, 0b11111111, 0b11110000 };

int main(void)
{
  ...

  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 12, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_CLK is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 2, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_CS is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 10, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_TX (MOSI) is push pull
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE, 11, gpioModeInput, 1);    // US1_RX (MISO) is input

  ...
  
  USART_InitSync_TypeDef config = USART_INITSYNC_DEFAULT;
  config.master       = true;            // master mode
  config.baudrate     = 1000000;         // CLK freq is 1 MHz
  config.databits     = usartDatabits8;
  config.autoCsEnable = false;            // CS pin controlled by hardware, not firmware
  config.clockMode    = usartClockMode0; // clock idle low, sample on rising/first edge
  config.msbf         = true;            // send MSB first

  USART_InitSync(USART0, &config);
  USART0->ROUTE = USART_ROUTE_CLKPEN | USART_ROUTE_TXPEN | USART_ROUTE_RXPEN | USART_ROUTE_LOCATION_LOC0;
  USART_Enable(USART0, usartEnable);

  while (1)
  {
    Transmit(TxBuffer, sizeof(TxBuffer));
    Delay(2000);
  }
}

void Transmit(const uint8_t* buf, int len)
{
  // Pull CS (SYNC) low
  GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    // Wait until FIFO is (half) empty
    while( !(USART0->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXBL) ); 

    // Put next byte into FIFO
    USART0->TXDATA = buf[i];
  }
  
  // Wait until transmissiob is complete
  while( !(USART0->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );

  // Pull CS (SYNC) high
  GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA, 2);
}
```

The USART has a three stage queue (two FIFO registers and a shift register). So by checking the TXBL flag, it's possibly to put new bytes into the queue while the previous bytes are still transmitting. That way it's easy to keep the queue filled such that the USART does not need to pause between bytes.

At the end, the TXC flag is checked to ensure that all bytes in the queue have been fully transmitted before CS/SYNC is pull high.